# what is the .filter method that I could use instead of running of a for loop

Tags: javascript, web

I am creating a function that takes in an array and changes elements equal to "Tolken" to "Tolkein":

```js
let changeName = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == "Tolken") {
      arr[i] = "Tolkein"
    } return arr
  }
}
```

What is the equivalent `.filter()` method that I could use in place of a for loop?

Comment: Copy and paste your code into your question directly please. As for using a filter method there would be no point in using one when you are just wanting to modify elements as you would ultimately be doing more loops (either from own code or within native code) than you are now

Comment: On a side-note, if you're referring to the author of *Lord of the Rings*, it's _"Tolkien"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can map over the array and return the updated value via a ternary.

`arr.map(element => element === 'Tolken' ? 'Tolkein' : element)`

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work just fine, my bad on not being able to post the code clearly. Stack kept on prompting me to type in the code differently, and when I did I got different errors